# Drawable disappears when shared between listview and view

Tags: android

I created a listview with drawables say 1,2,3.
I created a button which also has drawable 1.

When I click on the listview item with drawable 1, the drawable from the button disappears.

Any ideas?

Comment: what kind of drawables are they?  Can you post the code or xml that sets the drawables, or if you're using a state list drawable, can you post the xml code of that drawable?

Comment: Your drawables need to have different names. I dont think you can have an element in an xml defined as android:id="@+id/drawable1" for one item, and the same for another.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem may be caused by the fact that drawables are always shared from a constant `Drawable` source. If you want to change the characteristics of one of your drawables, you need to call `mutate()` on it so that your other drawables sharing the same base are not affected. With acknowledgments to Google:

```
Drawable star = context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.star);
if (book.isFavorite()) {
  star.mutate().setAlpha(255); // opaque
} else {
  star. mutate().setAlpha(70); // translucent
}
```

[Here](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/05/drawable-mutations.html) is the page where that came from.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem: It was in our API.

Basically, drawables cannot be shared. So the drawable was getting added to the ListView and the same drawable was added to a button. The drawable from the listview disappeared.

Hence, I created 2 array lists with the same drawables; I couldn't think of anything else.
And now the drawables don't disappear.

Comment: Also these drawables were getting added from a web resource.

Comment: It would be interesting to see your code - Drawables can and in fact are _designed_ to be shared, so you shouldn't have to make 2 lists to get this working.